# Disable intellij springboot dashboard

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea

Intellij now comes with a springboot dashboard. I have been brave enough to enable it, but now I want to disable it because it confuses me.

Where do I find the settings? In settings I see nothing

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> **Intellij 2017.2**

You can disable/deselect the `Show in Run Dashboard` configuration option in the `Run/Debug Configurations` dialog, accessed via `Run > Edit Configurations`.

To do the same thing in Intellij 2017.3, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48168984/8200937).

To do the same thing in Intellij 2018.3, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53771214/8200937)

Comment: In IDEA 2017.3 this option seems to have been removed.

Comment: It has no shorcuts!

Comment: For anyone encountering this issue in Intellij 2017.3, see the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48168984/8200937).

Comment: For anyone encountering this issue in Intellij 2018.3, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53771214/8200937)

Answer (score 23):

> **Intellij 2017.3**

You can disable by removing the Spring Boot dashboard:

- Go to `Run/Debug Configurations`
- In the `Defaults` configuration, select the `Spring Boot` dashboard and click on the `-` button

[image: intellij2017.3]

Comment: What an inane place to put that option.

Answer (score 20):

> **Intellij 2018.3**

The Defaults apparently got replaced by `templates`. And you can only move configuration types in and out of the Run Dashboard.

To do so for, say **all Application** Run/Debug Configurations, you have to

- `Edit Configurations...`
- `>` select `Templates` category on the left
- `> Configurations available in Run Dashboard`
- `>` select the category you want to remove
- `>` hit the `-` button

[image]

EDIT: Found it on Jetbrain's documentation: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html#run-dashboard

Answer (score 1):

For version 2017.2.

- Go to section: "Run / Debug Configurations" -> Click Defaults
- Enable / Disable: "Confirm rerun whit process termination"

[Configuration dialog box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SKyb.png)